# How to prevent json serialization (or deserialization) of member of type I can't change?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, devexpress

I receive an exception when deserializing [RecurrenceInfo](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraScheduler.RecurrenceInfo) in a big project:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot populate list type DevExpress.XtraScheduler.CustomFieldCollection at Newtonsoft.Json....   <<< omitted 20 Newtonsoft internal calls

The problem is reproducable with this MCVE:

```
RecurrenceInfo test = (RecurrenceInfo)RecurrenceBuilder.Weekly(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue).ByDay(WeekDays.Monday | WeekDays.Tuesday | WeekDays.Wednesday | WeekDays.Thursday | WeekDays.Friday).Build();
var copy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecurrenceInfo>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test));
```

I've noticed that in json there is this empty `CustomFields`:

```
"Recurrence": {
    ...
    "OccurrenceCount": 1,
    "CustomFields": [],
    "Id": "ef7ff4c3-9a3f-4cea-ab08-aa5f63e58c8c",
    ...
```

If I **remove** it from json, then there is no exception.

Because the project is big, it's a hassle to change something. So I am looking for a way to do it with minimum effort and affect on the rest.

### Question

Given:

```
public class A
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public RecurrenceInfo B { get; set; }        
}
```

How to [exclude property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10169648/1997232) `B.CustomFields` from being serialized (or deserialized)? Ideally via some attribute(pseudocode):

```
[JsonProperty]
[CustomResolver(typeof(MyCustomResolver))]
public RecurrenceInfo B { get; set; }
```

I suspect the answer is "no, you have to specify custom resolver as deserializer settings" (I am trying to avoid that), but maybe someone sees something I don't or can think of a nice trick or a totally different solution?

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot modify `B` at all, and you also cannot easily modify your project settings?

Comment: @dbc, I can't modify `RecurrenceInfo` type. Not sure what you mean with `B` or project settings. I can modify `A`, adding more properties. Currently my workaround is to serialize/deserialize `B` value as xml using another `string` property (which works flawlessly).

Comment: Then, assuming you have some custom contract resolver type `MyCustomResolver`, you could apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(AlternateContractResolverConverter), typeof(MyCustomResolver))]` to `public RecurrenceInfo B { get; set; }` where `AlternateContractResolverConverter` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40599731/3744182) to [JSON .NET Custom Name Resolver for Sub-Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40597532/3744182).

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dbc, maybe. I am not able to test it right now. I am currently more happy with my solution (another property) and keeping the question opened for devexpress experts, maybe they will add something. Otherwise I would just delete/close question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply prevent a property of being serialized using the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, but take care which library you are using. `System.Test.Json.Serialization` or `Newtonsoft.Json` because the attribute is called the same on both and will not throw an error, just not work if your cross the libraries.

Comment: Where should I put this attribute to prevent `B.CustomFields` from being serialized?

Comment: You should put it over the B custom fields declaration. Just on top of the propery you want to ignore.

Comment: `RecurrenceInfo` is a type defined in library, I can't put attributes there.

Comment: Maybe could you inherit the object like C : RecurrenceInfo and hide the variable with an ignore attribute on top ?

Comment: Inheriting? Hmm.. not sure. Perhaps I should try [adding attribute at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14663763/1997232).