# Deserialize JSON with Dashes (Kebab Case) in Property Names in C# Using NewtonSoft.JSON

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

I have an object I am attempting to deserialize with Newtonsoft.Json but it's giving me trouble due to properties containing dashes. The **event-data** property has a dash for example.

```json
{
    "signature": {
        "timestamp": "3421342",
        "token": "88f79ede5e9af44d6a2",
        "signature": "a57233ab698324dbf1ca9dff"
    },
    "event-data": { ... }
}
```

I don't have control over the `BaseEvent` model I am deserializing to but I did extend it to `MyEvent` to add some custom code for other stuff. So I am unable to decorate `[JsonProperty]` on properties. So I need to do this using either a contract resolver or some other more global method but ideally localized to just this model (an attribute decorator of some sort).

I was able to add this `KebabCaseNamingStrategy` decorator on my model which appears to be exactly what I need but it didn't do anything until I used the `new` keyword to hide the base class member. Then `EventData` gets deserialized (although the child properties on it containing dashes are not deserialized).

```cs
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(KebabCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class MyEvent : BaseEvent
{
   public new EventDataObject EventData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(KebabCaseNamingStrategy))]` only applies to properties declared by that type.  It (apparently) doesn't apply to base class properties, and definitely doesn't recursively to properties of referenced objects in the serialization graph.

Comment: To change naming strategy for an object and all nested objects, see [JSON .NET Custom Name Resolver for Sub-Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40597532/3744182).  You may need to create your own `KebabCaseContractResolver` to use the accepted answer as-is.  Or you could enhance it to add an second constructor for `AlternateContractResolverConverter` that takes a naming strategy type.  Does that answer your question sufficiently?

Comment: I tried inheriting the `DefaultContractResolver` to create a `KebabCaseContractResolver` but the entire object is null when deserialized as shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8T4osw

Comment: I'm really surprised they have a naming strategy already in the core library but no way to easily decorate an object to respect kebab case

Comment: The basic idea is that Json.NET defines a contract for each type, then serializes according to that contract.  You are expecting an attribute applied to a derived class to change the contract for base class properties.  Opinions could differ on whether that is actually desirable.

Comment: Fair enough. So I guess my only option is to pull the type into my code. The whole point of this library was to provide the type but seems sort of useless without a bunch of mapping code laying around somewhere. I'd rather have it directly specified on the model how these properties should be handled.

Comment: The correct usage would be `[JsonConverter(typeof(AlternateContractResolverConverter), typeof(KebabCaseContractResolver))]` not `[JsonConverter(typeof(KebabCaseContractResolver))]` because a contract resolver is not a converter.  But it turns out that `AlternateContractResolverConverter` had a bug or limitation making it not work when applied to a type instead of a property.  You can see a fixed version here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q8kDw2.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're dealing with [Mailgun.Models.SignedEvent](https://github.com/belidzs/Mailgun.Models.SignedEvent)? Here is a working solution using a KebabCaseContractResolver.

Extension to do the kebab conversion:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToKebabCase(this string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return input;

        var result = char.ToLowerInvariant(input[0]).ToString();
        for (var i = 1; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var currentChar = input[i];
            if (char.IsUpper(currentChar))
            {
                result += "-" + char.ToLowerInvariant(currentChar);
            }
            else
            {
                result += currentChar;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And the contract resolver itself:

```
public class KebabCaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName.ToKebabCase();
    }
}
```

The class where you process the request:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public async Task<MailgunEvent> ProcessSignature(HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var signedEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignedEvent>(requestBody, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new KebabCaseContractResolver() });

        //do some validation

        return signedEvent.EventData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stig has again shone upon us with his infinite wisdom!