# Facing Issue when Convert JSON to String

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, json.net

I am convert Json to Json String.

```
string callbackResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Getting result like :

```
 {
  "data": "{\r\n  \"DemoData\": {\r\n    \"value\": \"value1\"\r\n}",
  "Status_cd": 1
}
```

I want Result Like :

```
 {
  "data": {
    "DemoData": {
      "Value": "value1"
    },
    "Status_cd": "1"
  }
}
```

alos try with :

```
`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result`)
```

but not working for me.here result is a dynamic parameter.

need to save json in String but in unescape format
can anyone help please?

Comment: Your desired result is not valid JSON. So no, unless you are willing to accept invalid json, nobody can help. And also the result you are getting does seem a bit off. Seems like `result.data` is a string and not an object. Please show the definition of your `result` object

Comment: Hello, first question is what is result. And just for clarification, you mean to get result like: {"data":{"value":11},"status_cd":1}?

Comment: update my question with valid json.Please check if solution is possible.

Comment: It seems you are double-serializing, you serialized something, stuffed the resulting json into `data` property and then serialize the object with that property. Perhaps you need to make `data` have the type of whatever you serialized into it instead.

Comment: You could apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(RawConverter))]` to the `data` property, where `RawConverter` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539360/3744182) to [How can I serialize and deserialize a type with a string member that contains “raw” JSON, without escaping the JSON in the process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40529125/3744182).  In fact I think this may be a duplicate, agree?